# How to add Custom Tab in Magento Product Description Page

Tags: magento-1.9, tabs

I am new in Magento, I want to add three custom tab in Megento Product description page after "Product Description" Tab

Also I have created an attribute with "Product Details" as Textarea, Specification as Textarea, Ware & Care as Textarea in admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code after Description block in catalog.xml files

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="Your_attribute_name" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Your tab name</value></action>
 </block>
```

you can add id in the above way for any number of tabs needed hope this helps.

You can also follow this [link](http://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-tabs-on-the-product-page/)

Comment: Hi Donika very thanks, But can you tell what will be the Your_attribute_name and  detailed_info in the above answer